# What is problem in my restapi client qt code or setting

Tags: c++, qt

I will make rest api library same restsharp using qt. I made test code for Http Get Request but it was not working.

Then I followed error message, I installed openssl in window and reinstalled openssl toolkit using qt maintenance tool, but I can't receive response data

Then I checked openssl settings, Url, code and api

All normal

main.cpp

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "restmanager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

   RestManager* rest = new RestManager();
   rest->ConnectServer();

   const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
   QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                    &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
       if (!obj && url == objUrl)
           QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

restmanager.h

```
#ifndef RESTMANAGER_H
#define RESTMANAGER_H

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QUrlQuery>

class RestManager
{
public:
    RestManager();
    template<class T>
    T GetData();
    void ConnectServer(QString url);
    void ConnectServer();
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;

};

#endif // RESTMANAGER_H
```

restmanager.cpp

```
#include "restmanager.h"

RestManager::RestManager(){

}

template<class T>
T RestManager::GetData(){

}

void RestManager::ConnectServer(QString url){

}

void RestManager::ConnectServer(){
   QUrl myurl;
   myurl.setScheme("https");
   myurl.setHost("kr.api.riotgames.com");
   myurl.setPath("/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/xaml");

   QUrlQuery query;
   query.addQueryItem("api_key", "RGAPI-bdb3dde5-2112-44c0-a1e8-532b9f86e9d1");

   myurl.setQuery(query);

   qDebug() << "URL : " << myurl.toString();

   QNetworkRequest request;
   request.setUrl(myurl);
   request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


   QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);

   qDebug() << "DATA : " << reply->readAll();
}
```

result

URL :  "https://kr.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/myname?api_key=myapikey"

DATA :  ""

Normal request result

```
{
   "id":"myid",
   "accountId":"myaccountid",
   "puuid":"mypuuid",
   "name":"myname",
   "profileIconId":3799,
   "revisionDate":1586869853000,
   "summonerLevel":183
}
```

If I missed anything, please reply or can you tell me the right way?

Comment: Taking a wild guess, you don't have the correct certifcates installed to access that URL.

Comment: Install Fiddler and observe the request/response on the wire.  That will enable you to see if it's a network issue, an auth issue, or a problem in your code.

Comment: I get the correct data if I send the following request: https://kr.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/myname?api_key=RGAPI-bdb3dde5-2112-44c0-a1e8-532b9f86e9d1 . The problem in you code is that you don't wait for request is finished after sending it with `manager.get(request);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest you need to do this:

```
QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);

while (reply->isFinished() == false) {
    // sleep a half second or so
}
qDebug() << "DATA : " << reply->readAll();
```

Or preferably, setup a finished event signal/slot connection to the request object:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#finished

Sample code here: https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Downloading_Files_QNetworkAccessManager_QNetworkRequest.php

Comment: Thank 
Progress has been made in solving but TLS initialize failed error occur